# Error in running Android app on Emulator

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I'm testing an app developed with Apache Cordova by using an emulator. I've previously created a Neuxs 5 AVD.

The emulator is launched in a window, no error is displayed in the Terminal:

```
$ cordova run android
ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
No target specified, deploying to emulator
No emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus5
Waiting for emulator...
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
```

But just after that, I've got this message in the emulator window:

> Unfortunately, Launcher3 has stopped.

And I can't test my app. How could I move forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your image sources for emulators. Create specific emulator with sdk you wish. Run it from and manager. 
This error is from very old emulator sources. Make sure your studio and sources are updated.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't been able to update image source in Android SDK Manager, but via Android Studio it worked.